# Modeling mongodb subobjects in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am running into issues after adding a sub-object to my mongo documents. The query no longer returns results, even though I've added an object to my model to store the new sub-object.

I believe the issue is in adding the class for the sub-object to the object model. I can't seem to find any references anywhere online, so perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing?

Mongo elements look as so:

```
{
    _id: [id],
    Name: "Paul",
    Phone1: {
        Name: "Work",
        Number: "15551234567"
    },
    Phone2: {
        Name: "Work",
        Number: "15551234567"
    }
}
```

In C# my model looks as so:

```
public class PersonModel {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Phone Phone1 { get; set; }
    public Phone Phone2 { get; set; }
}

public class Phone {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

My query looks as so:

```
    public async Task<List<PersonModel>> GetPerson(string name)
    {
        var people = new List<PersonModel>();

        var allDocuments = await PersonCollection.FindAsync(
            ds => ds.Name == name);


        await allDocuments.ForEachAsync(doc => people.Add(doc));

        return people;
    }
```

Any references to a working example would be appreciated.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: What kind of query issues you are running into ? Any stack trace / error message ?

Comment: There aren't any errors being generated, it isn't returning any values. Any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can simplify this a little bit and just try `return allDocuments.ToList()` but I don't know if that solves your issue. The key thing is to check if  `var allDocuments ...` returns anything from the database

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I did put a break point before returning, and allDocuments is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The above implementation is correct. After many hours of trouble shooting it turned out I didn't have the datapoint in my database that I was querying against. Unbelievable.

If anyone else is struggling, I also found this guide that confirmed I was dealing with the subobject correctly: https://www.codementor.io/pmbanugo/working-with-mongodb-in-net-1-basics-g4frivcvz